# Get text from link use jQuery

Tags: jquery, text

I want to get text from link `<a class="active">...</a>` which was created by tab-slider in wordpress like in the picture.

[image]

here are my jquery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var text = jQuery('.mk-tab-slider-nav a.active').text();
        alert(text + "");
    });
```

only if I use `jQuery('.mk-tab-slider-nav a')` it has all the texts from all `<a />`.

but it just get empty when I use `'.mk-tab-slider-nav a.active'` or `'.mk-tab-slider-nav .active'` or `'.mk-tab-slider-nav:first-child'` just to check it gets empty also.

Please help me, what could happen to `<a />` that cause we can not get text by `.text()`

Comment: Try with .html() and please post your full html

Comment: I can not get full html myself, its wordpress project and thats html code was created by tab slider in wordpress

Comment: $('.mk-tab-slider-nav').find('a.active').html(); try this

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem, but you can try this: add an `id` to the `<a>` tag and try again `var text = $('a#someid').text();` If it works, something may: you have more than 1 `a.active` tag, The text of one is null or empty. Another case: `.mk-tab-slider-nav` is not unique

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your code. it's working fine

Comment: Possibility is if the entire mk-tab-slider-nav is created after the DOM load event then none of these solutions will work so first address that!

Comment: Hi when I try .html() and alert it shows "undefined".
and its still empty with other ways.

Comment: Hi when I use jQuery('.mk-tab-slider-nav a').text() it shows all correctly but 
jQuery('.mk-tab-slider-nav a').html() it only shows "1456". and a.active is still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an "empty" query because the `active` classname is added after the document ready event... That classname is added when the tab slider plugin starts (or, when someone clicks on a tab)...

You need to have a look on the plugin and their event (if it exposes an api set)...

a dirty solution could be applying a watch on the dom...

```js
jQuery(document).on(
  "tabSliderActiveText", (event, data) => {
    console.log("TEXT", data);
  }
);

jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  let selector = '.mk-tab-slider-nav a.active';
  
  let interval = window.setInterval(() => {
    let links = $(selector);
    if(links.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
  
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    $(document).trigger("tabSliderActiveText", {
      text: links.text(),
      item: links
    });
  }, 200);
  
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mk-tab-slider-nav">
  <a>FOO</a>
</div>
<div class="mk-tab-slider-nav">
  <a>FOO 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mk-tab-slider-nav">
  <a>FOO 2</a>
</div>
<div class="mk-tab-slider-nav">
  <a>FOO 3</a>
</div>
<div class="mk-tab-slider-nav">
  <a>FOO 4</a>
</div>

<script>
  //Mock the WP Plugin
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        document
        .querySelector("a")
        .classList
        .add('active')
        ;
      }, 3000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I think you are right I use  window.setTimeout( show_popup, 5000 ) and it seems to work, but your code is very complicated I cant not understand now. is there a way to make it waits for 5s setTimeout like I did at first but then get text after I click another a link right away as the active class change fast? I'm so new please help me.

Comment: You need to have a look on the plugin you're using... Every good plugin exposes a set of APIs, for example, I suppose, it exposes some JavaScript event like "onTabChange" where you can attach a callback... Go on the main site of that plugin!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($('div.mk-tab-slider-nav a.active').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mk-tab-slider-nav">
  <a href="#" >123</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">456</a>
</div>
```

Working example